# How to implement properly mapDispatchToProps on redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've seen two ways to implement mapDispatchToProps

First way:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return { actionMapped: bindActionCreators(courseActions, dispatch) };
}
```

Second way:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return { actionMapped: () => dispatch( courseActions() )};
}
```

Which one is more efficient? Is there any scenario that I should use a specific one? Is one of them "the recommended one"?

Answer (score 1):

There are several valid ways to "bind" your action creators when connecting a Redux component.  Here's some examples:

```
    import {action1, action2} from "myActions";
    import {bindActionCreators} from "redux";

    const mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) => {
        return {
            manuallyBoundAction : (...args) => dispatch(action1(...args)),
            autoBoundAction : bindActionCreators(action2, dispatch),
            multipleActionsTogether : bindActionCreators({action1, action2}, dispatch)
        }
    };

    const MyComponent = (props) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={props.manuallyBoundAction}>Run First Action</button>
                <button onClick={props.autoBoundAction}>Run Second Action</button>
                <button onClick={props.multipleActionsTogether.action1}>Run Third Action</button>
                <button onClick={props.multipleActionsTogether.action2}>Run Fourth Action</button>
            </div>
        )
    }

    export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);

    // or, you can use the "object shorthand" for mapDispatch:
    export default connect(null, {action1, action2})(SomeOtherComponent)
```

All of those ultimately result in functions that wrap up your action creator, and automatically pass its return value to `dispatch()` when called.

I personally recommend the "object shorthand" approach.  To me, there's never a good reason to write an actual `mapDispatch` function by hand.

Answer (score 0):

If `courseActions` is an object of actions it's easier to just pass the actions object to the [connect method](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) as the `mapDispatchToProps` parameter:

> If an object is passed, each function inside it is assumed to be a
>   Redux action creator. An object with the same function names, but with
>   every action creator wrapped into a dispatch call so they may be
>   invoked directly, will be merged into the component’s props.

Example:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, courseActions)
```

The [`bindActionCreators`](https://redux.js.org/api/bindactioncreators) does the same things, but you'll need to explicitly pass `dipsatch`:

```
const mapDispatchToProps =(dispatch) => 
    bindActionCreators(courseActions, dispatch)
```